# One line coffeescript "return if" iterating an array

Tags: coffeescript

This is my code (not working)

```
return monitor if (monitor.uuid is $scope.selectedMonitor) for monitor in $scope.monitors
```

I want to return monitor if the if is true and I'm trying to do in one single line. Is it possibile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `when` keyword:

```
getSelectedMonitor = ->
  return monitor for monitor in $scope.monitors when monitor.uuid is $scope.selectedMonitor
```

This generates the following JS:

```
var getSelectedMonitor = function() {
  var monitor, _i, _len, _ref;
  _ref = $scope.monitors;
  for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    monitor = _ref[_i];
    if (monitor.uuid === $scope.selectedMonitor) {
      return monitor;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Many thanks. Do you know if it is possible to append an "else" statement? Something like this: **when condition else null**